# Can humans become angels in Heaven?

Tags: angels

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Humans become Angels?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1955/can-humans-become-angels)

I have always wondered if in the afterlife humans can decide to become angels, and I have always wondered what is the difference between an archangel and an angel?

Comment: It may be beneficial to specify _which_ religions/denominations/etc, and what your definition of 'angel' is, as there are a number of differences.

Answer (score 7):

> I have always wondered if in the afterlife humans can decide to become
>   angels

No.  [Angels are entirely different than humans, created for a different purpose](http://christiananswers.net/q-acb/acb-t005.html#1).

> what is the difference between an archangel and an angel

[Archangels are simply angels with a higher rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archangel).

Answer (score -3):

Depends on how close you follow Scripture.

Enoch is said to have became 'Metatron' which is a type of Archangel?  So I guess depending on weather your believe the Bible is the only valid book or weather you know these choices were made by men and thus subject to mistakes.

Jude quotes directly from the Book of Enoch so I am going to assume even if this book is not divinely inspired as others are this book should carry some weight.

I know I should not quote Wiki put anyway:  [Metatron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metatron)

Comment: Paul quotes from Greek poets - it doesn't mean their work should all inherently "carry some weight" :)