# Were humans once angels?

Tags: heaven, angels, fall-of-man, earth, humanity

**Are humans fallen angels who are being given the chance to earn their place in heaven again?**
I was reading somewhere that this is true. The source gave no scripture references, however. Please give all answers from a biblical standpoint. I do not care of what denomination you are. Just show me in the word. Is there any scripture that backs up the claim that humans wew once angels? Thank You.

Comment: Even if this weren't overly broad, it's pretty much already got an answer at http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1955/can-humans-become-angels

Answer (score 2):

The Bible doesn't support this at all, so there is no scripture reference to give. Although perhaps there is a negative one.

Speaking of Jesus' incarnation, the author of the epistle to the Hebrews says:

> Hebrews 2:16 For verily he took not on him the nature of angels; but he took on him the seed of Abraham. (KJV)

That is, Jesus came to save men, not angels. This is why he took on human nature, not angelic nature. And it obviously also means that men are not angels. There is also Psalm 8, which is partially quoted in Hebrews 2.

> Psalm 8:3-5 When I consider thy heavens, the work of thy fingers, the moon and the stars, which thou hast ordained; [4] What is man, that thou art mindful of him? and the son of man, that thou visitest him? [5] *For thou hast made him a little lower than the angels*, and hast crowned him with glory and honour.

So, men are not angels, but a little lower than the angels.

Comment: I'd like to point out that these verses could be interpreted differently. The Hebrews verse may likely be referring to the angel's immortality and man’s mortality based on the preceding verses which explain that Jesus took on a mortal body. A similar interpretation could be made of the second quote. Also, Luke 20:36 speaks of resurrected people who become equal to the angles.  In other words, these verses suggest a difference between angles and men but do not say whether it is a difference of "species" or heavenly vs mortal status.

Answer (score 0):

God created humans with mud and gave him the breath of life. He named him Adam, gave him a partner and made Eden garden for them. Will God do this if humans were fallen angels?

Comment: Apparently the angels thought eve was pretty attractive though :) Maybe angles are fallen humans. (joke)